# Nested List — Get list item of parent list

Tags: c#, list, class, nested, parent-child

i want to write a C# function which returns "alamaba" when i pass "Montgomery".

2nd example: Sitka --> Alaska

here is the list of the example:

```
List<PopulationUSA> result = new List<PopulationUSA>();    

        PopulationUSA usa = new PopulationUSA("Population in USA", 316128839, new List<PopulationUSA>());
        result.Add(usa);

        PopulationUSA alabama = new PopulationUSA("Alabama", 4833722, new List<PopulationUSA>());
        usa.Items.Add(alabama);

            alabama.Items.Add(new PopulationUSA("Birmingham", 212113, null));
            alabama.Items.Add(new PopulationUSA("Montgomery", 201332, null));
            alabama.Items.Add(new PopulationUSA("Mobile", 194899, null));

        PopulationUSA alaska = new PopulationUSA("Alaska", 735132, new List<PopulationUSA>()); 
        usa.Items.Add(alaska);

            alaska.Items.Add(new PopulationUSA("Juneau", 32660, null));
            alaska.Items.Add(new PopulationUSA("Ketchikan", 8214, null));
            alaska.Items.Add(new PopulationUSA("Sitka", 9020, null));
```

here is the class:

```
    public class PopulationUSA
{
    public PopulationUSA(string name, int value, List<PopulationUSA> items)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
        Items = items; 
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public List<PopulationUSA> Items { get; set; }
}
```

How can i do that?
Thanks

Comment: it is really unclear what you are asking or where your problem is. In addition it would be good to show an example of what you have tried so far

Comment: What you have tried? Do you know how to use linq for this?

Comment: You can find the first state with a city with that name. `result.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Items.Any(c => c.Name == "Birmingham"))?.Name ?? "Unknown"`  Switch to `Where` if you want all the states with a city with that name.

Comment: I would recommend restructuring your class. A class defined with a list of the same class in it doesn't indicate well how to use it.

Comment: @BlakeThingstad So a TreeViewItem should be redesigned?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I doubt that, If he would know, he probably would not ask this question

Comment: @RomanoZumbé - I think it makes sense when used correctly. With a `TreeView` structure it absolutely makes sense, but it helps that the names are descriptive to what it is used for (and *Item* for a *TreeView*). At the *very* least, OP could make the name of the class more descriptive than "PopulationUSA".

Comment: @RomanoZumbé I wouldn't say so because the name of it indicates the use of the structure. I'm just saying that we would have had no idea that the OP was using PopulationUSA at the top level to represent the USA, 2nd level to be the States and the bottom to be cities if the OP had not posted code showing that.

Comment: there are several ways to solve your problem. Have you ever heared of recursion? Please post a first attempt to solve your problem by your self and we can help you with the rest. This is not a code writing service

Comment: I just figured out that i can access each entry of the list in my javascript code in asp.net mvc because i convert the list to a json string before i use the list. So the problem is solved. Sorry for the bad description. Thanks for all your answers!

Answer (score 0):

you can add this method to the PopulationUSA class

```
  public string FindParentsOfGrandChildren(string _name)
    {
        List<PopulationUSA> parents = Items.Where(s => s.Items.Any(c => c.Name == _name)).ToList();
        if (parents != null)
        {
            string listparents = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < parents.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                     listparents += parents[i].Name;
                }
                else
                {
                    listparents += ", " + parents[i].Name;
                }
            }
            return listparents;
        }
        else
        {
            return "Not found";
        }
    }
```

then use it like this in your example:

```
 string WhereDoIBelong = usa.FindParentsOfGrandChildren("Montgomery")
```

it would be much better as a recursive method, finding parents of any type (not just "grandchildren") but that is your work!